# Why does the typeof function not working in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, typeof

- I use the GCC compiler (version 9.2.0)
- I want to use the typeof function in C but it raises an error (**error: expected expression before 'typeof'**)
- If you need more info, just ask me .

```
int a = 5;
double b;
//the expected result is "0", but it raises an error instead...
printf("%d", typeof(a) == typeof(b));
```

Comment: It raises an error for the same reason that `int == double` raises an error.

Comment: C++ has `typeid` which can do this but I don't think C has that yet.

Comment: @tadman - The more accurate C++ equivalent would be `decltype`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Even better, yeah!

Comment: GCC has `__builtin_types_compatible_p(TYPE1, TYPE2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the behavior you want by dropping gcc extensions and using standard C `_Generic`:

```
#define my_typeof(x) _Generic((x), int: 1, double: 2)

printf("%d", my_typeof(a) == my_typeof(b));
```

The only catch is that you have to type out support for every type manually.

Comment: Thanks', it woks, the only problem is that, do you know why I can't use this function ?
(i'm using Code::Blocks btw )

Comment: @Mobento What function? printf?

Comment: What I mean is why this function (typeof) don't work for me and works in other systems

Comment: @Mobento Because you are using it wrong, as indicated by comments?

Answer (score 3):

GCC has a built-in function called [`__builtin_types_compatible_p`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200904234035/https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005ftypes_005fcompatible_005fp) that takes two arguments that are types (not expressions) and returns the `int` value 1 if the types are compatible, or 0 if they are incompatible.

OP's example could be written as:

```
int a = 5;
double b;
printf("%d", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b)));
```

From the [online documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20200904234035/https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005ftypes_005fcompatible_005fp):

> Built-in Function: *int* **__builtin_types_compatible_p** (*type1*, *type2*)
>
> You can use the built-in function `__builtin_types_compatible_p` to determine whether two types are the same.
>
> This built-in function returns 1 if the unqualified versions of the types *type1* and *type2* (which are types, not expressions) are compatible, 0 otherwise. The result of this built-in function can be used in integer constant expressions.
>
> This built-in function ignores top level qualifiers (e.g., `const`, `volatile`). For example, `int` is equivalent to `const int`.
>
> The type `int[]` and `int[5]` are compatible. On the other hand, `int` and `char *` are not compatible, even if the size of their types, on the particular architecture are the same. Also, the amount of pointer indirection is taken into account when determining similarity. Consequently, `short *` is not similar to `short **`. Furthermore, two types that are typedefed are considered compatible if their underlying types are compatible.
>
> An `enum` type is not considered to be compatible with another `enum` type even if both are compatible with the same integer type; this is what the C standard specifies. For example, `enum {foo, bar}` is not similar to `enum {hot, dog}`.
>
> You typically use this function in code whose execution varies depending on the arguments’ types. For example:
>
> ```
> #define foo(x)                                                  \
>    ({                                                           \
>     typeof (x) tmp = (x);                                       \
>     if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), long double)) \
>       tmp = foo_long_double (tmp);                              \
>     else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), double)) \
>       tmp = foo_double (tmp);                                   \
>     else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), float))  \
>       tmp = foo_float (tmp);                                    \
>     else                                                        \
>       abort ();                                                 \
>     tmp;                                                        \
>    })
> ```
>
> *Note:* This construct is only available for C.