# How to use typeof in clang compiler without warning?

Tags: c, clang

I want to use typeof in clang but not `__typeof__`. If I use typeof without declaring it I get warning the following warning

```
vector.c:14:5: warning: extension used [-Wlanguage-extension-token]
    vec_init(&a,5);
    ^
./vector.h:27:26: note: expanded from macro 'vec_init'
    ((vec_ptr)->data) = (typeof((vec_ptr)->data)) malloc((capacity) * (sizeof((*((vec_ptr)->data)))))      \
                         ^
1 warning generated.
```

then I thought defining it might solve it so I added the following code:

```
#ifndef typeof
#ifdef __clang__
#define typeof(x) __typeof__(x)
#endif
#endif
```

With the added pre-processor definition I get the following error:

```
In file included from vector.c:1:
./vector.h:5:9: warning: keyword is hidden by macro definition [-Wkeyword-macro]
#define typeof(x) __typeof__(x)
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

but I get no error if I use `__typeof__` instead.
How to solve this warning issue on clang?

Comment: maybe just don't cast the result of `malloc` in your `vector` code. It is pointless and potentially dangerous. The only reason of doing it is compatibility with C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point of posting this answer, `typeof` is *not* a standard feature but an experimental language extension. As such, if you insist on using it,   do so with the awareness that you aren't writing standard C - and get warned accordingly from strict compilers.

However, `typeof` used to be a GNU extension but it will be included in C23. Although compiler support for adding this to strict standard C is still shaky (neither clang 15 nor gcc 12.2 will allow it when compiling as `-std=c2x`).

Either way, `typeof` is not not a preprocessor `#define` but a keyword, so you can't use it with `#ifndef`.

For now, you can compile in clang or gcc with `-std=gnu2x`, until compiler support for C23 settles. But you still can't compile with `-pedantic` or you'll get a warning for using extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Anytime you want to deactivate a warning just feed a flag to the compiler that says `-Wno-[warning-name]`

In your case:
`-Wno-language-extension-token`

Also, please, do NOT try to sweep this under the rug with clever code, either you acknowledge the warning and keep your code standardized, or you still acknowledge it but de-activate it.

That way if anyone uses your code with all warnings enabled they will still be warned that you are using extensions.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing, the `typeof` and `__typeof__` operators are not in the language standard, but rather a compiler extension. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12081502/14193797)). `typeof` and `__typeof__` are [only standard in C23 and onwards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23).

So in the first example, the compiler is trying to warn you that you are using a compiler extension, thus losing portability.

In the second example, you are defining `typeof`, using a macro, and that hides `typeof` (which is a keyword), so the compilers give a warning as well.

You can discard it using the `-Wno-language-extension-token` flag (in [neervana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991030/14193797) answer, note that this will turn off warnings for all `language-extension-token` warnings, not just this one), use the `-std=gnu2x` flag (in [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991072/14193797) answer note that it will still not compile if you are using `-pendanic`,) or [defining your own using `_Generic`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844523/14193797).

Or, resolve your problem by don't cast the result of `malloc` in your `vector` code (as [tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990777/how-to-use-typeof-in-clang-compiler-without-warning/74991172#comment132339304_74990777) said).